# Excel - How to split values of 70 items equally into 6 groups

Tags: excel

So I'm trying to create an Excel sheet to split the values of 70 items into six groups.

For reference, this is to divide my grandma's estate evenly for her six children. I have approx. 70 items and their appraised values in an Excel sheet, but not sure the best way to go about this. I was hoping to use Solver, but haven't been able to figure it out.

Ideally I could make it so people could pick specific items that they want and run the Excel sheet again to re-balance all the values.

Thanks!

Comment: By value so each get an equal share or you can factor in any sentimental value to each person. Then it becomes a problem that can be solved with sumproduct() and Solver.

Comment: What would I even be doing sumproduct on though? I've done a bunch of Solver problems but this one is stumping me.. @SolarMike

Comment: 1 sumproduct for each person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So set this up, based on a thrown together set of values.

[image]

Each sumproduct is held to be <= to the (total value / 6)-10. You may want to reduce this to 5 or 2 etc but the smaller you go the harder it is to solve due to the values of the items.

I have done this for 30 items, there is a limit to the number of variables in the Solver - if you hit that then you might consider pairing items, or manually setting some will help, see below.

You might want to add something for sentimental value - I will leave you to consider that.

As for manually setting some items then you can set those items to one, move them to the top or bottom and remove them from the Solver variable cells - that way they won't get changed, but they still need to be included for the value. If the values are similar then they can be taken out if the differences are ignored by the parties.

So, edited the model, see below. Note that 1 item is not allocated. This could be addressed by changing the constraint controlling cells J9:J38 but it comes down to the difficulty of finding an exact solution and that is also why the 10 can be adjusted...

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted to do. Really appreciate it.